# Display Tag with search feature (like Jquery)

Tags: displaytag

I want to know how to implement Display tag with Search feature, like on giving a letter , based on that , the data in the tables should sort or display, if there is no data, an error message should display.

Comment: Have an example here http://www.bkumar.co.uk/2012/03/12/displaytag-table-search-using-datatables-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Displaytag don't have serach inbuilt. You can make use of jquery/js in this case.